# Locked out of VPS - No SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, vps

I've broken the SSH on my Debian 6 VPS (no GUI). When I try and connect, I get the following message:

```
ssh: connect to host XXX port 22: Connection refused
```

I have no physical access to the machine. Is there another way I can connect to the machine using default Debian features? Telnet doesn't work

I must have made a typo in the SSH config file.
Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with the VPS provider to ensure there are no current problems on their end?  They may also be able to provide some means/suggestions for resetting your password(s).

Comment: No, it's my fault. I changed the SSH config file and did a reboot but the service didn't come back :(

Comment: For the next time after you've reinstalled the server: Linux is not Windows. You don't need to reboot when changing a config file for a daemon. Just type `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` while you're logged in. Your session will not be closed, and you can try the new settings with a second ssh connection.

Comment: That didn't work. Terminal said it couldn't find the file... I'm thinking I should have asked myself why before rebooting.

Comment: Look into /etc/init.d for something with ssh, that should be it.

Comment: Your VPS provider should have a "backup" procedure for login into the console of the VPS, ask them or publish the name of you provider in case someone can guide you for the console login procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your VPS provider offer a 'virtual console' to access the server? If so, use it!

If not, you might be able to open a trouble ticket with them and ask if they can get root access to fix the sshd config. Something like `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`.

Comment: Nice if you have Digital Ocean,
Suicide if you have singlehop.